# Unity + Kinect + Arduino = Nuilnitialize failed

Tags: unity-game-engine, arduino, kinect

I'm connecting my Kinect (SDK 1.8) to control an Arduino using Unity (simple on/off depending on the position of the hand, with a *StandardFirmata* protocol loaded in the Arduino *Mega2560*). It works well for a few minutes untill Unity sort of overloads and stop sending data to the arduino.
I thought about adding a delay in my code in order to fix this, but I dont know if it will solve the problem.

The error message that I'm getting in the game screen is *"Nuilnitialize Failed - Device is not genuine."*.

And here is my code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Uniduino;

public class GestionRelais : MonoBehaviour {
    public Arduino arduino;
    public GameObject NoeudATracker;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        arduino = Arduino.global;
    }

    void ConfigurePins() {
        arduino.pinMode(13, PinMode.OUTPUT);
        arduino.pinMode(9, PinMode.OUTPUT);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (NoeudATracker.transform.position.x<=0) {
            arduino.digitalWrite(13, Arduino.HIGH);
            arduino.digitalWrite(9, Arduino.LOW);
        } if (NoeudATracker.transform.position.x>0 ) {
            arduino.digitalWrite(13, Arduino.LOW);
            arduino.digitalWrite(9, Arduino.HIGH);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks by advance for any help !
Cheers,

Etienne.

Comment: I am not sure this question contains enough details to be answered. Anyway, I would start by making your class **stateful** and modify `update()` so that the *pin's value is changed only when strictly necessary* (e.g. `x` value crosses `0` in either direction). This should limit the stress over the *communication channel* as well as over the *Arduino* hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If you have USB 2.0 and Unity 4.6 above versions give this error. Try to plug kinect to USB 3. If there is less graphics try to download unity 4.6 version and try.